# Is there a better way to update my guest port number without recreating kitchen instance?

Tags: chef-infra, test-kitchen

Below is my `kitchen.yml`

```
---
driver:
  name: vagrant
provisioner:
  name: chef_zero
  # You may wish to disable always updating cookbooks in CI or other testing environments.
  # For example:
  #   always_update_cookbooks: <%= !ENV['CI'] %>
  always_update_cookbooks: true

verifier:
  name: inspec

platforms:
  - name: centos-7

suites:
  - name: default
    driver:
      network:
      - ["forwarded_port", {guest: 3000, host: 3000}]
    run_list:
      - recipe[meteor-app::default]
    verifier:
      inspec_tests:
        - test/smoke/default
    attributes:
```

Then I've changed guest port number to the following

```
      network:
      - ["forwarded_port", {guest: 4500, host: 3000}]
```

Is there a better way to update my instance without recreating it.

Comment: `kitchen converge` will re-run your run_list without destroying/recreating it.

Comment: But this won't do a `vagrant reload`.

Comment: The generated `Vagrantfile` is below `.kitchen/kitchen-vagrant/`. You can issue a `vagrant reload` there. Maybe `kitchen converge` updates the `Vagrantfile`, maybe you have to manually edit it.

Comment: Unfortunately the kitchen converge does not refresh the port numbers.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, there is no official way to do this in Kitchen. You can go under the covers and run the relevant vagrant commands directly but you would be better off just `kitchen destroy`ing and rebuilding the instance.

Comment: Agreed. I will use this method for the time being